# TFS Build Automation - Web Deployment Project error

Tags: tfs, msbuild, web-deployment-project

I'm trying to build a web deployment project using TFS automated build process. When I build the project directly in Visual Studio 2008, it works fine. But from TFS, I get the following error:

```
"C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\TestProduct\TestSolution\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (EndToEndIteration target) (1) ->

"C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\TestProduct\TestSolution\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (CoreCompile target) (1:2) ->

"C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\TestProduct\TestSolution\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (CompileConfiguration target) (1:3) ->

"C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\TestProduct\TestSolution\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (CompileSolution target) (1:4) ->

"C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\TestProduct\TestSolution\Sources\TestSolution.sln" (default target) (6) ->

"C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\TestProduct\TestSolution\Sources\WebDeployment\WebDeployment.wdproj" (default target) (48) ->

(CreateVirtualDirectory target) ->

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(676,5): error : Some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

I made sure that NETWORK SERVICE account has permission to access all the web folders. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have the web deploy project installed on the build TFS server.

This article should give you more information

[RTW version of Visual Studio 2008 Web Deployment Projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/01/25/announcing-rtw-of-visual-studio-2008-web-deployment-projects-wdp.aspx)

Comment: We had web deployment projects installed. After we migrated to TFS 2010, all those errors went away. It could have been some configuration issues with our old TFS.